# SoapClient can not open local WSDL (nginx, php7-fpm)

Tags: soap, nginx, wsdl, local, php-7

I'm running nginx and php7-fpm and have problems with the SoapClient accepting local wsdl files. I use a local file (like /api/backend/server/reservation/reservation_v012.wsdl) but I get a 502 Bad Gateway error. When I use "file:/" I get an error "failed to load external entity".

__getTypes() is not delivering any types. The 502 Bad Gateway error occurs exactly at this position, when __getTypes() is called.

Any idea why it's not running like it does with PHP 5.3 before?

Comment: Just to confirm: Your code is like    $client = new SoapClient('/api/backend/server/reservation/reservation_v012.wsdl');     $client->__getTypes();

Comment: I have tested the above snippet on  PHP 7.0.0RC3, it works when run via php-cli. Could you provide more detail about your PHP version and what else you changed when you moved from PHP 5.3.

Comment: We are running PHP version 7.0.0-dev (cli) (built: Sep 13 2015 19:09:42)
The only thing I've changed so far ist to get $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] now from file_get_contents('php://input')

Comment: I've just upgraded to PHP 7.1.0-dev (cli) (built: Sep 23 2015 19:09:28) but I get the same error.

Comment: Ok, good test. Where are you seeing the '502 Bad Gateway' Error? Is that what PHP is logging when it tries to __getTypes(); ?

Comment: I use SoapUI and as Xdebug is still not available for php 7 I have to user var_dump ;)
The error occurs just after calling __getTypes. In the nginx error.log I get:
`2015/09/24 16:18:03 [error] 16679#0: *182 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.17.20.184, server: ~^(?<subdomain>***\d{2})\.*******\.net$, request: "POST /services/012/reservation/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/api/run/php7-fpm.socket:", host: "api.*******.net"`

Comment: php-fpm will have it's own log. Usually specified by the 'error_log' directive in php-fpm.conf. This will give you a more specific message generated by PHP.

Comment: The error log defined in php7-fpm.conf is empty but I get the following in syslog:

`Sep 24 16:58:25 cabdev2 kernel: [179746.248520] php7-fpm[16767]: segfault at 10 ip 00000000006e5946 sp 00007fffd0abd6b0 error 4 in php7-fpm[400000+ab6000]`

Comment: This is getting beyond my skillset. If you cannot resolve the issue, consider opening a bug with PHP. This one is similar to yours: [https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70017]. If you get a solution, please add a note on this question for others.

Comment: I recently had a similar problem directly after upgrading to PHP7. Turned out that WSDL cache had to be re-initialized, because somehow PHP5 and PHP7 use the same cache, but the cache created with PHP5 seems incompatible with PHP7. Solved by setting the WSDL cache lifetime to 1 second temporarily: `ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', 1);`